# A uniform rule for matching numeric and symbolic expressions for inverse of complex numbers?

Tags: pattern-matching

I am trying to do some substitution on the basis of pattern matching. I am trying to replace $\frac{1}{a+i b}\to\frac{a-ib}{a^2+b^2}$ in the following way,

```
ruleExp = {Power[Plus[Complex[0,-1],a_],-1]->(a+I)/(a^2+1),
        Power[Plus[Complex[0,1],a_],-1]->(a-I)/(a^2+1),
        Power[Plus[a_,Times[Complex[0,1],b_]],-1]->(a-I b)/(a^2+ b^2),
        Power[Plus[a_,Times[Complex[0,-1],b_]],-1]->(a+I b)/(a^2+ b^2)};

1/(a - I b) /. ruleExp (*Out:= (a + I b)/(a^2 + b^2)*)

1/(a + I b) /. ruleExp (*Out:= (a + I b)/(a^2 + b^2)*)

1/(a - I  ) /. ruleExp (*Out:= (a + I)/(a^2 + 1) *)    

1/(a + I  ) /. ruleExp (*Out:= (a - I)/(a^2 + 1) *)
```

As you can see I have to write 4 rules to match patterns with symbols and different signs, as I understand it this is robust but **is there some smarter way to match all such expressions for numeric as well as symbolic expressions for all signs with less than these four rules?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
lst = {1/(a - I b), 1/(a + I b), 1/(a - I), 1/(a + I)}
```

**1.**

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand @ lst, ExcludedForms -> {_Complex}]
```

> [image]

**2.**

```
rule = pat : Power[u_ + _Complex  v_., _] :> 
   FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[pat], ExcludedForms -> {_Complex}];

lst /. rule
```

> [image]

**3.**

```
rule2 = Power[u_ + v_. Complex[x_, y_], p_.] :> 
   Power[u + v Complex[x, -y], -p]/(u^2 + v^2);

lst /. rule2
```

> [image]